# Purpose of minSupported and maxSupported parameters in getVersion API

Tags: cadence-workflow

I find [getVersion API](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.uber.cadence/cadence-client/2.6.0/com/uber/cadence/workflow/Workflow.html#getVersion-java.lang.String-int-int-) to be a bit hard to grasp. After some manual experiments with workflow changes, I found out that it's perfectly fine to have such a piece of code:

```
val version = Workflow.getVersion("change#1", 1, 1);
val anotherVersion = Workflow.getVersion("change#2", 2, 2);
```

1. Does it mean that the integer version is assigned to a `changeId` and not workflow instance? Does a single workflow instance/execution keep a set of integer-based versions?
2. What is the purpose of `minSupported` and `maxSupported` parameters? Why simply not to use an API like below?

```
val version = Workflow.getVersion("change#1")
if (version) {
   // code after "change#1" changes
} else {
   // code before "#change#1" changes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct, the version is assigned to a `changeId` not a workflow instance. This allow versioning each piece of the workflow code independently. It allows fixing bugs while workflow is already running and didn't reach that part of the code.
2. The main reason is validation. The `getVersion` call records in the workflow history `maxVersion` when the code was executed for the first time. So on replay the correct version is used to guarantee correct replay even if the `maxVersion` has changed. When a branch is removed the `minVersion` is incremented. Imagine that such code is deployed by mistake when there is a workflow that needs the removed branch. The `getVersion` is going to detect that `minVersion` is larger than the one recorded in the history and is going to fail the decision task essentially blocking the workflow execution instead of breaking it. The same happens if the recorded version is higher than the `maxVersion` argument.

Update: Answer to the comment

> In other words, I'm trying to come up with a situation where using
>   many different changeIds and not exceeding maxVersion=1 is not enough

They are enough if you don't perform removal of branches. But if you do then having validation of the minimal version is very convenient. For example look at the following code:

```
val version = Workflow.getVersion("change", 0, 2);
if (version == DEFAULT_VERSION) {
   // before change
} else if (version == 1) {
   // first change
} else { 
   // second hange
}
```

Let's remove the default version:

```
val version = Workflow.getVersion("change", 1, 2);
if (version == 1) {
   // first change
} else { 
   // second hange
}
```

Now look at the version without min and max:

```
var version1 = Workflow.getVersion("change1");
var version2 = Workflow.getVersion("change2");
if (version1 == DEFAULT_VERSION) {
   // before change
} else if (version2 == DEFAULT_VERSION) {
   // first change
} else { 
   // second hange
}
```

Let's remove the default branch:

```
var version2 = Workflow.getVersion("change2");
if (version2 == DEFAULT_VERSION) {
   // first change
} else { 
   // second hange
}
```

Note that a workflow that used the last sample code is going to break in unpredictable way if it is routed by mistake to a worker that doesn't know about version2, but only about the original default version. The first example with min max version is going to detect the issue gracefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still can't get my head around `minVersion`/`maxVersion`, though. Would you be able to picture an example that shows where incrementing these integers is necessary? In other words, I'm trying to come up with a situation where using many different `changeIds` and not exceeding maxVersion=1 is not enough.

Comment: Updated the answer